# Wordpress Conditional page types such as is_home,is_front_page, is_single not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, conditional-statements

I have been trying to use several conditional statements using is_home/is_front_page or is_single and they are not working in my theme. Below is an example on such code:

```
<?php if(is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>
<?php if(function_exists('show_flexslider_rotator'))
echo show_flexslider_rotator('homepage_fexslider' ); ?>
```

This loads my Flexslider, but when I go to page 2, the slider remains on the page.

I have used these statements successfully in other themes.

Do I need to add support for this feature in my functions.php?

How can I troubleshoot this?

My home.php code is as follows:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>
<?php if(function_exists('show_flexslider_rotator')) echo   show_flexslider_rotator( 'homepage' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>  
<div class="row below-banner">
<div id="site-content" class="span8">

<div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <h2>What's new</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="posts span8">

<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') :1;         query_posts('cat=-35&paged=' . $paged);?>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>

<?php endwhile;  ?>
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<h2>No Posts Found</h2>
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>


</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

We would need more info/code in order to give a definitive answer, but my best guess is that you need to add a wp_reset_query() somewhere.

A quick test: add wp_reset_query() immediately before the conditional statements and see if that resolves the issue. If so, then you need to find the offending query and make sure it is reset at the appropriate time.

Comment: I have added my page code I also have tried wp_reset_query(); with no success.

Comment: Did you try putting the `wp_reset_query()` before the `if(is_front_page() || is_home() )` (just as a test/sanity check)?

Comment: I just tried putting <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> above my conditional tag and it still does not work. any other ideas?

Comment: Ahh, I think I didn't fully understand what you're trying to do. You have paginated blog posts as your home page, and you only want the slider to appear on Page 1 of those blog posts (and not Page 2.) In that case, you'll want to work the is_paged() function into your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with wordpress conditionals like is_single is that they don't work outside a functions in functions.php

So the solution is to place the conditional within the function and call that function using add_action probably.

The code here [is_single not working in functions.php](http://nabtron.com/is_single-not-working-in-functions-php-wordpress-solved/8064/) explained how it won't work outside the function and how should it be instead